# R caret package, tuning parameters using a data set

Tags: r, r-caret

I rewrote my question:

I am using R with the caret package.

I partitioned my data set in 3 parts: training, validation and test sets.
The validation set will be used to tune the training parameters.

The train function of caret, tunes the training parameters via resampling (bootstrapping by default).
Is there a way to tell the train function to use my validation data set parameters instead of resampling?

Right now I have to use a loop that you can see in the example below.

EG:
    Code:

```
    library(caret)
    set.seed(3)
    data("segmentationData")
    #
    # Partition data set in training, validation, testing.
    #
    inTraining <- createDataPartition(segmentationData$Class, p=.60, list=FALSE)
    training <- segmentationData[ inTraining,]
    notTraining <- segmentationData[-inTraining,]
    inValidation <- createDataPartition(notTraining$Class, p=.50, list=FALSE)
    validation <- notTraining[inValidation,]
    testing <- notTraining[-inValidation,]
    #
    # The model will be trained using method 'rpart', 
    # it has cp (Complexity Parameter) as only tuning parameter.
    #
    # The training will be tuned using different values for cp.
    # We'll choose the cp that maximizes accuracy.
    #
    cps = c(0, 0.001, 0.003, 0.01, 0.03)
    maxAccuracy = -1

    for(currentCp in cps) {

        #
        # Call train function using currentCp and train control set to 'none'.
        #
        f <- train(Class~., training, method = 'rpart', 
                       trControl = trainControl(method = "none"), 
                       tuneGrid = data.frame( cp = currentCp ))

        #
        # Predict on validation data set.
        #
        pr <- predict(f, validation)

        #
        # Select cp that maximizes accuracy.
        #
        cm=confusionMatrix(pr, validation$Class)
        currentAccuracy = cm$overall[[1]]
        if(currentAccuracy > maxAccuracy) {
            cpMaxAccuracy = currentCp
            maxAccuracy = currentAccuracy
        }
    }

    #
    # Output.
    #
    cpMaxAccuracy
    maxAccuracy
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that? You are then using the validation data in your trainig process.

Comment: @AlexR The original data set can be split in training, validation and test sets. Validation set is used to tune training parameters. My question is whether in caret there is an automated way to tune the training parameters automatically other than cross-validation. Right now I have to do it with a loop.

Comment: Could you add your code with a loop? Maybe it will be clearer what are you looking for...

Comment: @JoteN I changed my question and added code example